# How to make Stack rebuild the Cabal file when `package.yaml` has changed?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

When I use stack I have the following files in the root:

- `stack.yaml`
- `package.yaml`
- `myProject.cabal`

The last one is built automatically by `stack build`, based on the other two. Accordingly, I expect `myProject.cabal` to be updated when the other two files change, but that is not the case. As far as I can tell one must delete the cabal file for a new one to be generated.

First obvious question is: Why? Why doens't Stack rebuild the cabal if obviously needs to be changed?

Second question: How do I tell Stack to rebuild the cabal file? I don't want to manually delete the cabal file every time I do a version change or tweak `package.yaml`.

---

What I've tried:

One option is to manually delete the cabal file manually, which just seems like a terrible workflow. The other option is to always delete the cabal file (with a custom makefile) this seems hacky and would trigger a full rebuild (since the cabal file changed) everytime!

Comment: AFAIK `stack` is supposed to regenerate the `.cabal` file when the `package.yaml` changes. Was the `.cabal` file changed in some way, so `stack` wouldn't want to overwrite these changes?!

Comment: Just to be sure, because you don't explicitly write this: you *are* running `stack build` (or `stack test` or `stack run`) after changing the other files? And this still doesn't change the `.cabal` file?

Comment: @sjakobi was right! When I tested the cabal file was modified. At that point one must delete it, but otherwise Stack will update it correctly on `stack build`. If you want to add the comment as an answer I'll accept it.